# ASP Format text in .txt file for HTML

Tags: html, asp-classic, text-files

I have created some ASP that commits text to a .txt file and then returns that back to a HTML page. Now I have a minor problem in that I need to add `<br />` between the lines in the text file.

So the .txt file looks like this:

```
Hello World 1

Hello World 2

Hello World 3
```

But it will display like this

```
Hello World 1 Hello World 2 Hello World 3
```

My ASP Code looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="BugRequest_edit.asp">
<br>
<br/>

<input type="text" name="Name" size="62">

<input type="submit" value="Report">
</form>

<%
Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("Bug.txt"), 1)
Response.Write(f.ReadAll)
f.Close

Set f=Nothing
Set fs=Nothing
```

Any ideas or pointers would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You should be more clear, add what "between the text stored in the text file"?

Comment: ah that should have a < br > there but its actually put a break in, instead of the text!

Comment: Ready line by line and put a <br> at the end of each line instead of reading the entire text from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CR and LF are not marked in HTML as line end. Use paragraph tags, i.e. 
Read the file line by line, add `<p>` before and `</p>` after the string containing each line of data and then output it by Response.Write.

```
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    Response.Write("<p>" & f.ReadLine & "</p>")
Loop
```

Alternatively you may use the `<pre>` tag:

```
Response.Write("<pre>")
Response.Write(f.ReadAll)
Response.Write("</pre>")
```

Comment: Sorry I am still new to this, CR and LF? What would the syntax look like to add the <p> and </p> tags look like? Thanks.

Comment: Stefan, I would just use Replace: `Response.Write(Replace(f.ReadAll, VbCrLf, "<br />"))` - should work just fine. @Methexis for your information as well. :)

Comment: Tried all of the above options and they work great, i settled with Stefans second response as it seems cleaner! Thanks all really appreciate it!